# Bug facing six tiles

Tags: probability, independence

A motivated bug with poor depth perception needs to cross six square tiles placed in a line.  She needs to cross the tiles in sequence from 1 to 6.  After sufficient training to develop totally random crossings with complete tiles, each of the tiles now has the right margin of the tile removed in the following order from tile 1 to tile 6:  1%, 2%, 4%, 8%, 16%, and 32%. She will fall through the tile where it has been removed. What is the probability that she will cross all six tiles?  Why and what is the suitable formula? A simple solution of 0.99 x 0.98 x 0.96 x 0.92 x 0.84 x 0.68 is not suitable since the right side of the tiles has been removed and the tiles do not appear to be totally independent.

Comment: What do you mean by "the tiles do not appear to be totally independent"?

Comment: Could you please add a diagram or a more detailed explanation? What does "right margin of the tile removed" mean exactly? Is each tile narrower than the previous one?

Comment: Correct,  each tile is more narrow than the one before by what is called the removed tile. But all the removed tile is to the right. If the removed tile were more evenly distributed like a symmetric pyramid or in pieces like a pachinko pinball machine, then passing each tile would be more independent. It is a fair assumption to say that if the bug starts to the left, then making in to the end is higher than if she starts to the right. Let us assume that variance between one tile and the next is sigma^2 and is constant.

Comment: Is the bug moving on a straight line? A drawing would be really really helpful to understand your question.

Comment: No,  the bug is a bug.  It zigs and zags like bugs do. Sorry,  I am new to this and really trying to find a formula, so I do not know how to add drawings.   Imagine a stack of more narrow tiles stacked on top of each other. But instead of a symmetric pyramid,  all the tiles are moved to the left. Now lay those tiles down. The bug can  start anywhere on the first tile but the mean would be to start at the center of the tile.   It has a 1% chance of stepping into the 1% removed tile, but is not likely to do so.